# How Do I get InsertionTime of A Queue Message in C# Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I am using C# to create an Azure function using a QueueMessage trigger. I want to get the insertion time of the queue message.

In the code that runs the the function I have access to the message body as a string, as per the standard signature from the template in Visual Studio:

```
[QueueTrigger("url-content-300", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]string myQueueItem
```

However I want to get the insertion time of the message.

In the Python template it gives me the whole message queue object like the following:

```
msg: func.QueueMessage
```

which I can then deserialise as a Json Object:

```
result = json.dumps({
    'id': msg.id,
    'body': msg.get_body().decode('utf-8'),
    'expiration_time': (msg.expiration_time.isoformat()
                        if msg.expiration_time else None),
    'insertion_time': (msg.insertion_time.isoformat()
                       if msg.insertion_time else None),
    'time_next_visible': (msg.time_next_visible.isoformat()
                          if msg.time_next_visible else None),
    'pop_receipt': msg.pop_receipt,
    'dequeue_count': msg.dequeue_count
})
insertionTime = result.insertion_time
```

How do I do that in C# ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of retrieving it as a string you can retrieve it as a [CloudQueueMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.queue.cloudqueuemessage?view=azure-dotnet-legacy) which will contain the metadata you are after. E.g.

```
[QueueTrigger("...", Connection = "...")]CloudQueueMessage myQueueItem
//...
var content = inputQueueItem.AsString;
var insertionTime = inputQueueItem.InsertionTime;
```